# Outlook automatically print attachment pdf

Tags: outlook, automation

I would need to automatically print a pdf attachment that comes from a specific recipient in outlook 2016. Only the attachments. I have managed by rule to print the body of the message but NOT THE ATTACHED PDF. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you will need to code a plugin

Comment: Hello, sorry but can not do with a rule or something similar? plugin? You can specify name and if it is free or paid. Thanks.

Comment: Apply a rule but ONLY PRINT THE MESSAGE BODY.
Rule:
 1-reception of mail 2- of specific person 3-with attachments 4-print 5-without exceptions. I do not know what to try anymore. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I found this page for you. There you can find plugin you can buy or you can customise Outlook yourself

[How to Automatically print mails and attachment](https://appuals.com/how-to-prints-emails-and-attachments-automatically/)

Let scroll to **Method 2: Using Outlook to Automatically Print Email Attachments**

Then, you will only deal with the attachment name (detecting .pdf at the end) or its content type from the VBA code or the mail headers ...

Comment: Sorry it's the option I tried a couple of days ago but unfortunately when applying the rule in outlook does not allow run a script, I think Microsoft removed it a few years ago.Thx.

Comment: The last option is a VSTO plugin I believe ...  a big project for only one need ??  perhaps you will buy one

Comment: There has to be a free and outlook solution. I do not understand how you can not have the option. Has anyone had this need? I have looked in google but they are all post that refer to scipt and it is not possible to activate it by registering. Any solution? Greetings and thanks in advance.